# How does a tourist visa from VisaToRussia with Airbnb work?

Tags: visas, russia, airbnb

When applying for a tourist visa via [VisaToRussia.com](http://www.visatorussia.com), when it asks me for an address, am I required to specify a hotel or can I directly choose a location from Airbnb?

This differs from other questions as it is specific to how VisaToRussia operates.

Comment: Better check with the Russian consulate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I contacted visatorussia and got a quick answer to this question:

> If you do not plan to stay at a hotel, please leave the field blank. A
>   hotel will then be mentioned in your invitation for form's sake and
>   you will have to indicate the same hotel in your consulate application
>   form. This way you will obtain  a tourist visa with no complications
>   and once in Russia, you will be able to choose accommodation in
>   accordance with your convenience.

---

Keep in mind that if you do not stay at a hotel and if you stay longer than 7 business days, ensure that the owner of the place you're staying at, fills out a special russian form for the government indicating where you are staying. A hotel will do this automatically for you.